# How can i send the output of an sql statement

Tags: unix, teradata, dos2unix

I'm trying to make a script that sends mail to someone (with Unix) to receive the output of a statement. What I selected in that statement to send to the mail.
I already have a connection made through `Teradata`, I kept trying to make this reference but it doesn't work ..

If I'm trying to do with spool, like this and then to sent the email from that text file (probably `teradata` doesn't support spool):

```
spool file_name.txt
select * from db;
spool off;
```

This gives me an error:

> Failure 3706 Syntax error: expected something between the beginning
> of the request and the 'spool' keyword.

My question is how can I do this?

Comment: In Teradata use `BTEQ` or `FAST export` utility

Comment: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/bwmTub8T37PmQEaOVoPd1A/YN2MBvaY6iYBwK6v9Nm_aA